# How to find $1^k+2^k+...+n^k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science

I know how to come up with $F(n, k) = \sum \limits_{p=1}^n p^k$ recursively knowing $F(n, k-1)$.

But what if I want to find it in a very short time?

I know how to find fast $f_n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1} a_i f_i$, where $(a_1, ..., a_{n-1})$ are constants. It can be achieved using matrix multiplication in logarithmic time. I've heard that it is possible to solve this problem using similar method but I don't know how.

**Note**: For simplicity it is fine to get just F(n,k) modulo some prime number say $10^9+7$

Comment: [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSum.html) is a page that describes the problem you're interested in it, and several closed form solutions (I'm not sure how fast they necessarily are, but it'd be a good place to look).

Comment: An [article in English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) will help you.

Comment: @choco_addicted You should convert that to an answer.

Comment: @JoshChen No, I have not to. I leave comments and answers myself, not forced by someone. I can't provide detailed description about the topic, so I just showed a link. Is it wrong?

Comment: I just meant that your comment is a perfectly good answer to the OP's question and would serve very well as an answer :)